# what is the most efficient way to determine if any one of the number from given set of numbers is zero?

Tags: c++, c

In my project, I have to perform certain operations only if one or more numbers from the particular set are zero. I want this check to be the efficient one and don't want to perform multiple AND operations.

e.g. if there are 10 elements I need to perform following operation before getting the final answer

```
var_and= A1 && A2;
var_and=var_and && A3;..
.
.
var_and=var_and && A10;
```

This is how assembly code will look like(?).

Is there any better solution to this?

Comment: Who is responsible for putting the values? Maybe use a flag there and skip the checking part altogether?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Initially, all the values will be zero and simultaneously or may be one by one each value will become some non-zero value

Comment: Have a zero counter. Routines that add/remove/mutate numbers in the set need to update the zero counter.

Comment: This is not an answer but are you sure you are not optimizing prematurely or optimizing a part of the code which isn't the bottleneck

Comment: If you really have 10 or more values, these should arguably go in an array. And figuring out if one of them is zero e.g by looping over the array until you find one like that.

Comment: I am trying to achieve it with minimum assembly instructions. Looping will be bad if only the last element is zero. So I wanted to know if is there any cheapest solution available

Comment: @lax there's unavoidably always going to be a last element

Comment: Use `std::any_of`.

Comment: And fewest assembly instructions does not mean fastest. It just means fewest instructions. You'll often get surprising efficiency simply by ensuring all the elements of the set are contiguous. Sorted if possible.

Comment: This isn't meaningful to optimize before 1) knowing the type of the data, 2) knowing the nature of the data - any patterns? is it sorted? and 3) knowing the amount of data. Any attempts to write code before all of that is known won't result in anything meaningful.

Comment: Maybe you should decide which language to use. C is not C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient way to do that is most definetly

```
std::any_of(v.begin(),v.end(),[](int x) { return x==0; });
```

Some compilers would even be able to vectorize it, so it's going to be hard to optimize it any further.

But the most important thing here is that you're saving your time that could be wasted on counting assembler instructions (which hardly even makes sense) and the time of potential readers of your code.

After you've finished your whole program, you can profile it and determine your bottlenecks. In the unlikely case this line is one of them, you'll have to figure out what exactly is going on - cache misses, IO, wrong branch prediction - and fix that specific problem.

Also another close option is

```
std::find(v.begin(),v.end(),0)!=v.end();
```

Comment: I don't have as modern a compiler as yours -- can you profile your answer vs the one given in http://stackoverflow.com/a/42384605/558639 and post the results?  I'm ready to be impressed...

Comment: @fearless_fool good thing we have the compilers [here](https://godbolt.org/g/dYbrZQ) :) As you can see, MSVC (CL 19) produced pretty much the same code, others (GCC, Clang, ICC) managed to do some loop unrolling with the `std::any_of` - could be somewhat beneficial, depends on the specific case. My local measurements showed almost no difference in timings, which was kind of my point I guess :D

Comment: The godbolt.org site is a GREAT tool: in this case, your any_of() approach emits 5 instructions in the inner loop, the "old school pure C" code emits 7.  Consider me impressed, and thank you for the enlightenment!

Comment: @fearless_fool to be completely honest, none of the compilers did vectorize it after all (I'm looking at you ICC), so there is still a little bit of possible speeding up. It would require some knowledge on the data part - the probability of zero encounter - and I recommend against it, but I cannot say it's not there:)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to point out is that "most efficient" is in the eye of the beholder.  Do you mean fastest?  Smallest code space?  Easiest to maintain?

If your compiler and hardware supports vector operations, I'd say take the product of the set and if it equals zero, you know that at least one element is zero.

So perhaps I'm missing something -- the following seems too simple -- but does this do what you want?

```
bool has_a_zero(int *values, int n) {
  while (n--) {
    if (!*values++) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

If that's not fast enough, you can do tricks like unrolling the loop to do chunks of N tests at a time (e.g. [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)).  Or if your set of values has an out-of-band value, you can use that to terminate the loop rather than manipulate extra registers.

But, as it is, you'd need to explain a bit more what you mean by "most efficient".

Comment: By efficient I mean fastest with less no of machine instructions.

Comment: Less instructions doesn't necessarily mean faster?

Comment: Fewest instructions total?  Or fewest executed?  And if the latter, in the average case or the worst case?  Consider that stopping at the first zero found doesn't help in the worst case but likely produces more code.  Unrolling a loop is often faster, but produces more instructions total.